# How can I read button text dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JavaScript and I am using a tag management tool to track certain user actions on my page.

For some background, I am trying to send the click text of an element to google analytics dynamically when a button gets clicked on. The tool I am used to has a built in data variable called "Click text". "Click text" returns a string contained in the textContent / innerText attribute value of that element, which is what I am trying to replicate in the new tagging tool.

I believe I can do this using JS code, but I am struggling on how to make it dynamic for all elements and not just elements of a certain class.

I was thinking after I target the element using the tool - it would be something like below but it is returning all the button clicks instead of the one the user clicks on:

```
$('button').text();
```

or

```
$(this).attr('displayText');
```

or

```
$(this).find('button').text("");
```

I might be trying to simplify it too much?

The button code throughout pages looks like the below (again it will be different classes/ids - I will use the tool to target what the "click text" JS/JQ fires on).

```
 <a class="button primary __button-primary link" href="mywebsite.html" 
 target="_self"> == $0
 "Hello world"
 ::after
 </a>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: could you show us your click event handler code?

Comment: It is using a built in app so in this case the settings are as followed: Fire on: User Action/Page Event   Event Action: Click Find Element By: Element Class Element Class: button.primary

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note the distinction between `$('button')` and `$('.button')`. The former selects button *elements*, which you don't have.

`$('.button')` (like most element or class selectors) returns a set of elements. You'd need to be more specific with your selector, or do something like `$('.button').first().text()`.

This is one of those cases where a positive ID would be good (if you're able to modify the markup). Then you'd do this:

```
$('#myButtonId').text()
```

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know that distinction! When you say positive ID - do you mean every element should have it's own ID and then the jquery above would work?

Comment: Just the elements that you know you'll want to target explicitly. In general, classes are better for CSS and jQuery, but cases like this need to be unambiguous.

Comment: Can I use $(this) to only get the button that was clicked on insread of first()?